# Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy - Google Analytics

Tags: caching, google-analytics, lighthouse

After Google Lighthouse check it detect that some scripts can be cached. On of it is Google Analytics (analytics.js). But I can't change Google's heaeders, so how to fix this warning in Google Lighthouse?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could look into something like `ServiceWorkers` - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests

Answer (score -1):

It is something related to the server configuration. You can't fix this with code as far as I know.